# Ubuntu autoinstall failed : block probing failed

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to autoinstall an Ubuntu 22.04 server and I'm using, for now, a rather minimalist `user-data` file, that I copied on a usb stick (created with `sudo mkfs.vfat -I -F 32 -n 'CIDATA' /dev/sdb`)

I provide below the content of the two files on the usb stick. Then I boot and start the auto-install (adding the `autoinstall` option to the boot command line).

Unfortunately, the installer stops with some errors :

```
...
start: subiquity/Mirror/apply_autoinstall_config
start:   subiquity/Mirror/apply_autoinstall_config/waiting
finish:    subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: cancelled
start:   subiquity/ErrorReporter/1687822728.270903587.block_probe_fail/add_info
start:   subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: restricted=True
finish:    subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: restricted=True
finish:    subiquity/ErrorReporter/1687822728.270903587.block_probe_fail/add_info: written to ..
finish:  subiquity/Filesystem/_probe
..
```

And after these finishing lines, the autoinstaller givens me access to a terminal and the install is stopped. And I do not know what I can do basically to solve this issue. Actually, I do not know if this an error from, say, subiquity and I can fill an issue, or a configuration issue on my side.

The **meta-data** and **user-data** files are given below :

**meta-data**

```
dsmode: local
instance_id: cloud-image
```

**user-data**

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:  
    hostname: myhostname
    username: ubuntu
    password: "$5$r3Kl6AKBqjA78VCX$4.Vuc56PR2faX3vLuqBxHxF796qiLhxuS4MacXtTt5C"
  keyboard:
    layout: fr
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
    allow-pw: true
  network:
    version: 2
    wifis:
      wlp2s0:
        optional: true
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp6: true
        access-points:
          "MY_WIFI_SSID":
            password: "MY_WIFI_PASS"
```

Thank you for your help.

I'm not very familiar with the autoinstall. I tried to look into the `/var/log/installer` and `/var/crash` directories.

grepping "ERROR" in the crash file, I find few 3 errors :

```
ERROR probert.network:768 set_link_flags failed
ERROR root:37 finsih subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: FAIL: cancelled
ERROR block-discover:596 block probing failed restrcited=False
```

Then in `/var/log/installer/block`, in the `discover.log` file, I see, among other logs, one `raise exceptions.TimeoutError()` from l590 in subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py

I'm wondering if this is the origin of the failure of the autoinstaller.

In the following lines in the discover.log file, after the raised exception, I see some elements :

```
Extracted multipath maps fields: ['ok']
Failed to parse multipath maps entry: ok: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'sysfs' and 'paths'
Extracted mutlipath paths fields: ['sda', 'WD-WX91AB4DFAJV', '[orphan]', '[undef]', 'ata-1.00', '[undef]', '[unded]', '[unded]']']
...
```

and at the very end, a merged storage config where I see the sda drive, the USB , etc.. I do not know if these elements are relevant.